# Jquery события выделения и клик

Tags: jquery

У меня есть тег textarea в которому я пишу текст. Как сделать чтобы когда я выделял слово, а потом кликал на кнопку, именно это слово становилось жирным. 
Любая помощь мне очень поможет
Сейчас у меня можно делать только содержимое тега (все текста) жирным. А мне надо отловить события и кинуть его в переменную и при клике делать его жирным

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.bold_text').click(function() {
  var $pole=$('.pole_text').css('fontWeight','bold').val();
  var $out=$('.out');
 });
});
```

```css
body {
 background: url(img/crossword.png), center, no-repeat;
 margin: 20px 40px;
 font-size: 22px;
}

* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.pole_text {
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #7FB2F0;
 max-width: 300px;
 max-height: 100px;
}

.bold_text {
 font-weight: bold;
 background: #ccc;
 width: 80px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius:3px;
 border: 1px solid #7FB2F0;
 background: #ADD5F7;
}
.header {
 margin: 20px 5px;
 // font-size: 18px;

}
.p_2 {
 margin-left: 20px;
 font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <main><button class="bold_text">Bold</button><br><br>
  <textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="text" class="pole_text"></textarea>
  <p class="out"></p>
 </main>
 

 
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: если хочешь, что бы тебе помогли, ты хотя бы  свои исходники добавь, за тебя что весь код писать?

Comment: а как здесь код снизу кинуть?

Comment: Нажми "редактировать" и добавь код

Comment: нажми править вопрос, и в редакторе увидишь на панели значок  с угловыми скобками, нажми на него и вставь код

Comment: насколько мне известно, нельзя применить к части текста в textarea какие-либо стили, как и использовать внутри нее html-теги. Посмотрите, как это делают в tinymce. Там textarea только хранит код, который выполняется внутри iframe, а редактирование происходит внутри этого же iframe

Comment: Я думаю можно, потому что на форумах это делают!

Comment: @VitalikSlobodyanuyk, это невозможно сделать именно в стандартном textarea. Вы можете либо сами попробовать имитировать поведение textarea, либо использовать какой-либо контейнер (например, div) со свойством [contenteditable](https://habrahabr.ru/post/126877/) или взять какой-нибудь плагин, предназначенный специально для этого.

Answer (score 1):

Я не так давно  интересовался этим вопросом. 
Textarea не поддерживает тегов и выводит их как текст. 
Делал я так: Выделял текст или нажымал кнопку после чего вставлялся открывающий тег выбранного елемента или если картинки всплывало окошко куда нужно было вставить текст ссылки, линк или _target. Дальше после нажатия еще раз кнопки добавлялся тег закрытия. Для пред просмотра была отдельная кнопка которая открывала спозиционированный блок над textarea блоком уже в нужном нам виде отображалось содержимое. Робота ето скажу вам , муторная и использывать нужно jquery

Comment: Я и хотел на jquery писать